# I want sidebar to move between right and bottom when resizing browser window

Tags: blogger, blogspot

Listed below are two examples of a floating sidebar that I want:

https://qxxrbull.blogspot.com/?m=0

https://stebalien.com/blog/howto-create-floating-sidebar-on-left/

When reducing the browser width, the right column of the blog floats from right to bottom, with the main or left column automatically resized to full width. I want similar effects on my blog:

http://mkhere.blogspot.com/?m=0

I tried to add

```
float: $endSide
```

in `.main-inner .fauxcolumn-right-outer {}` and `.main-inner .column-right-outer {}`, but it did not work.

Sorry, I am not a coder. I might have misunderstood the code snippets that I collected from several free Blogger templates and tutorials. Could anyone give me some hints to modify my code snippets? Thank you.

Comment: The first blog seems to have used Bootstrap Grid System for this purpose. Maybe I should spend sometime studying it.